# Centos 5 + vlan -> centos6 + vlan = что поменялось?

Tags: centos, сеть, route, vlan

Добрый день,

Переношу систему на новое железо и заодно ОС. Былоcentos 5.x, одна физическая сетевка + 2 vlan (eth1, vlan16, vlan31). Все работает, как часы много лет.

Сейчас CentOS 6.5, одна физическая сетевка + 2 тех же vlanа. Воткнут в тот же порт на свиче (это к тому, что все вланы там настроены). Все тоже самое, хостнеймы, ip - все..

**eth0**

```
[root@pg ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 | grep -vP '^#'DEVICE=eth0BOOTPROTO=noneONBOOT=yesHWADDR=08:60:6e:d6:9e:00
```

**eth0.16**

```
[root@pg ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0.16 | grep -vP '^#'VLAN=yesDEVICE=eth0.16ONBOOT=yesBOOTPROTO=staticTYPE=EthernetIPADDR=192.168.16.33NETMASK=255.255.255.0BROADCAST=192.168.16.255GATEWAY=192.168.16.1
```

**eth0.31**

```
[root@pg ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0.31| grep -vP '^#'VLAN=yesDEVICE=eth0.31ONBOOT=yesBOOTPROTO=staticTYPE=EthernetIPADDR=192.168.31.33NETMASK=255.255.255.0BROADCAST=192.168.31.255GATEWAY=192.168.31.1
```

модуль загружен

```
[root@pg ~]# lsmod | grep 8021q8021q                  25349  0garp                    7152  1 8021q[root@pg ~] /etc/init.d/network restartДеактивируется интерфейс eth0.16:                          [  OK  ]Деактивируется интерфейс eth0.31:                          [  OK  ]Деактивируется интерфейс eth0:                             [  OK  ]Деактивируется интерфейс-петля:                            [  OK  ]Активируется интерфейс loopback:                           [  OK  ]Активируется интерфейс eth0:                               [  OK  ]Активируется интерфейс eth0.16:  Determining if ip address 192.168.16.33 is already in use for device eth0.16...                                                           [  OK  ]Активируется интерфейс eth0.31:  Determining if ip address 192.168.31.33 is already in use for device eth0.31...                                                       [  OK  ][root@pg ~]# routeKernel IP routing tableDestination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface192.168.16.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0.16192.168.31.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0.31link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1005   0        0 eth0.16link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1006   0        0 eth0.31default         192.168.31.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0.31
```

Интерфейсы поднимаются, но работает только eth0.31 (через него пингуется и изнутри и снаружи, eth0.16 же не пропускает ничего). Что не так?

Всегда делал только на CentOS 5, там все работает..

p.s. файлы для вланов создавал в виде [ifcfg-ethX.id](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-networkscripts-interfaces_802.1q-vlan-tagging.html), и в виде [ifcfg-vlanid](http://xgu.ru/wiki/VLAN_%D0%B2_CentOS)

Comment: Сам себя пингует ? iptables ?

Comment: пингует, нету, selinux выключен

Comment: если сделать  ping -I  192.168.31.33 "любой хост"  и на "любом хосте" запустить  tcpdump ?!

Answer (score 1):

У вас в настройках виртуальных интерфейсов не определены физические интерфейсы.

PHYSDEV=eth0

Вот мой конфиг:

```
VLAN=yesDEVICE=eth0.8PHYSDEV=eth0BOOTPROTO="static"IPADDR=192.168.18.10NETMASK=255.255.255.0ONBOOT=yes
```

Comment: Это уже необязательно, т.к. физическое устройство указано в названии файла. Но все равно - это не работает

Comment: пакет vlan установлен? попробуйте выполнить:vconfig add eth0 4000ifconfig eth0.4000 10.10.10.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 upifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0должно работать,

Answer (score 1):

Проверь трассу до шлюза.По твоей таблице роутов весь трафик идет на шлюз 192.168.31.1Тебе надо прописать роуты правильно.